# regex string replace using Sublime 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime 3 for a string replace task inside a lengthy PHP file. I would like to achieve the following.

Turn all instances of this pattern (there are about 100):

```
$data['xyz']
```

Into this:

```
Mything()->settings->get('xyz')
```

Throughout the PHP file, the pattern is identical to above except the 'xyz' part differs from instance to instance and should be preserved by the regex.

Comment: I don't know sublime, but: replace `/\$data\[('[^']+')\]/` with `Mything()->settings->get(\1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using regular expressions**

Find:

```
\$data\['(.*?)'\]
```

Replace:

```
Mything()->settings->get('\1')
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FioiGT/1/)

Don't forget to enable **Regular Expressions** while using find and replace in SublimeText

Comment: This should still work if you exclude the single quotes.